# How to display the waveform for recording and make it synchronized with that when playing the record

Tags: android, record, amr, amplitude

I have met such a problem, which is to display waveform while recording, jusy like what is displayed in app recforge. The waveform should be displayed little by little as recording continues, and the waveform should be the same while playing the same record.

And I hope the recording format can be in amr.

Below is what I have tried:
Used getMaxAmplitude of mediarecord to get the value and draw it out using Drawline, this seems feasible, but the problem is when I play it out by referring the source code of ringdroid, I found the waveform was not synchronized with as of recording.

Then I just want to ask, how to make the waveform displayed as the same for recording and playing, and how to get the Amplitude of recording from cheapAmr.java

recforce :https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dje073.android.audiorecorderlite&hl=zh_CN

ringdroid:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ringdroid

Comment: Hey any luck in finding any example?